# Is there a way to use \( \) inside a listings environment as math delimiters

Tags: listings, algorithms

I have the following code

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{algocaption}{Algorithm} % defines a new caption label as Algorithm x.y

\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[1][
    {
        \captionsetup
        {
            justification=raggedright,
            singlelinecheck=false,
            labelformat=algocaption
        }
       \lstset
       {
            mathescape=true, 
            escapeinside={},  % I think I need to change this
            literate={\\\\[0pt]}{{}}1, 
            breaklines=false, 
            frame=tB,
            basicstyle=\scriptsize, 
            keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
            keywords=
            {
                ,input, 
                output, 
                return, 
              datatype, 
              function, 
                    in, 
                    if, 
                  else, 
                foreach, 
                  while, 
                  begin, 
                    end, 
            } 
            xleftmargin=0.4\textwidth,
            #1
        }
}{}
```

which should turn

```
\begin{algorithm}
input: int N, int D\\[0pt]
output: int\\[0pt]
begin\\[0pt]
res $\gets$ 0\\[0pt]  %% I manually edited this in overleaf
while N \(\geq\) D\\[0pt]
    N \(\gets\) N - D\\[0pt]
    res \(\gets\) res + 1\\[0pt]
end\\[0pt]
return res\\[0pt]
end\\[0pt]
\end{algorithm}
```

Into the following...

[image: Algorithm Desired]

but instead latex gives me...

[image: Undesired Algorithm]

I know I can use `$$` instead to get the desired result, but that is not what I am trying to do (this gets automatically formatted this way after exporting from emacs org mode, and as far as I know, the behavior cannot be changed). Additionally, I know I could add `''` to `escapeinside` but I'd really prefer not to add any extra characters. It seems like it should be possible to set the escape inside delimiters as `\\(` and `\\)`, but trying this does not work.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}



\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{algocaption}{Algorithm} % defines a new caption label as Algorithm x.y

\lstnewenvironment{algorithm}[1][]{\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,labelformat=algocaption}\lstset{mathescape=true, escapeinside={}, literate={\\\\[0pt]}{{}}1, breaklines=false, frame=tB,basicstyle=\scriptsize, keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,keywords={,input, output, return, datatype, function, in, if, else, foreach, while, begin, end, } xleftmargin=0.4\textwidth,#1}}{}




\begin{document}

%% Problematic
\begin{algorithm}
input: int N, int D\\[0pt]
output: int\\[0pt]
begin\\[0pt]
res \(\gets\) 0\\[0pt]
while N \(\geq\) D\\[0pt]
    N \(\gets\) N - D\\[0pt]
    res \(\gets\) res + 1\\[0pt]
end\\[0pt]
return res\\[0pt]
end\\[0pt]
\end{algorithm}

%% Desired
\begin{algorithm}
input: int N, int D\\[0pt]
output: int\\[0pt]
begin\\[0pt]
res $\gets$ 0\\[0pt]
while N $\geq$ D\\[0pt]
    N $\gets$ N - D\\[0pt]
    res $\gets$ res + 1\\[0pt]
end\\[0pt]
return res\\[0pt]
end\\[0pt]
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Can you create a single block of code that contains a minimal, working example? Something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing? The current code blocks cobbled together doesn't allow for that...

Comment: I have problems to compile your code.

Comment: Did you check the MWE? I am 100% sure that it works in overleaf because I just checked.